# LISP Write a function called cut-in-half that receives a list and create a new list whose elements are the first half and the second

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

I am having trouble with this function. we were asked at first "Write a lisp function that takes a list and an integer n, and returns the first n elements of the list, as a new list. In case n is less than 1, it returns NIL. In case n is beyond the length, the function returns a copy of the original list."

```
(defun take-n (list n)
     (cond 
     ((= n 0) ())
     ((null list) list)
     ((cons(car list)(take-n(cdr list)(- n 1)))))
    )
```

What I got so far from the question above is:

```
(defun cut-in-half(list)
    (let (x (ceiling(/ (length list) 2)))(let* (reverse list))
    (list (take-n list x)(cdr(take-n y x))))
)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a good place to use `subseq`. Unless the assignment here is to use recursion and not a built-in function...

Comment: Also it looks like you have some syntax errors in your second function. The syntax of `let` is `(let ((variable value) (other-variable other-value)) form)`. If you say `(let (x ... ))` that will set `x` to `nil`.

Comment: take-n could return list as a secondary return value, simply by writing (values () list) in case n is zero. Also the last clause cond is bad style imo, prefer having t as a test and (cons ...) as the associated clause body. Splitting a list in half is however a particular case for which Kaz's answer is better suited.

Answer (score 2):

See if you can build your homework around this idea:

```
[1]> (loop with l = '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
           for x on l
           for y = x then (cddr y)
           when (null y)
            return (values (ldiff l x) x))
(1 2 3 4) ;
(5 6 7)

[2]> (loop with l = '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
           for x on l
           for y = x then (cddr y)
           when (null y)
            return (values (ldiff l x) x))
(1 2 3 4) ;
(5 6 7 8)
```

This is the sort of thing I've done in the past implementing binary merge sort (for cutting a list in half, sorting the two halves recursively, the merging). Basically we have two cursors running through the list; one steps in double time, hitting the end of the list twice as fast (using `cddr` steps rather than `cdr`), which leaves the other cursor in the middle.

Note that in `loop`, the `for x on l` syntax is roughly the same as doing `for x = l then (cdr l)`, plus a termination test to end the loop when `x` becomes null. We could do it that way since we don't need a termination test on `x`. I.e.

```
[9]> (loop with l = '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
           for x = l then (cdr x)
           for y = x then (cddr y)
           when (null y)
            return (values (ldiff l x) x))
(1 2 3 4) ;
(5 6 7 8)
```

Which is nice since the `x` and `y` clauses follow the same form, and the contrast between `cdr` and `cddr` is made explicit.

To return a list of the two lists, use `list` instead of `values`. Since Common Lisp has multiple values, it's idiomatic to take advantage of that instead of allocating extra list cells.

Comment: Agree but instead of ldiff I'd rather "collect (car l) into first-half".

Comment: @coredump That's better since it avoids another scan of the first half of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of versions which are conceptually clean (no destructive operations, even implicitly), but perhaps mildly inscrutable.  Both do more work than any of the  obvious (implicitly) destructive versions.  Both make some attempt to use no functions which have non-constant time complexity other than functions they define themselves (so, for instance, no calls to `reverse` or `length`).  Both express iteration as tail recursion.

The purpose of both of these is to see how you can build things using only fairly primitive operations and not using destructive operations, and using no explicit iteration constructs but that this tends to cost you a bit more consing and time.

For me, the purpose is also to show that these 'clean' variants of problems are often a lot harder to understand than the 'dirty' variants.  This is, however, opinion.

Both return the two halves of the list as multiple values.  Neither are probably suitable as homework answers.

The first version works by:

- walking down the list computing its length and building a reversed copy;
- walking down that reversed copy accumulating it into one of two further reversed copies which are the results.

This version effectively walks the list twice and builds a complete reversed copy and then a complete reversed copy of *that*.

```
(defun halfify (list)
  ;; Return two values: a copy of the first half of LIST and a copy of
  ;; the second half of LIST.  'half' is defined as by (round (length
  ;; list) 2).
  ;;
  ;; This works by walking down the list to accumulate a reversed copy
  ;; of it and its length: half/accum does this.  When this is done,
  ;; rev/split then walks down the reversed copy accumulating a
  ;; further reversed copy into one of two accumulators.
  ;;
  ;; This walks the list twice, and conses essentially two copies of
  ;; it.
  (labels ((half/accum (tail n accum)
             (if (null tail)
                 (rev/split accum (round n 2) '() '())
               (half/accum (rest tail) (1+ n) (cons (first tail) accum))))
           (rev/split (tail n h1 h2)
             (cond ((null tail)
                    (values h1 h2))
                   ((> n 0)
                    (rev/split (rest tail) (1- n) (cons (first tail) h1) h2))
                   (t
                    (rev/split (rest tail) n h1 (cons (first tail) h2))))))
    (half/accum list 0 '())))
```

The second version works by:

- walking down the list to compute its length;
- splitting the list in halg using the computed length, accumulating the split (the leading part of the list) backwards;
- reversing the leading chunk using an accumulator.

This is slightly more efficient: it effectively walks the list twice (once to compute the length, and then two half-walks), but it only conses as much as the list, since it conses the leading half twice, once backwards and then once to reverse it.

Note that the tail of the list returned by this function shares structure with the tail of the original list: that's not true for the first function.

```
(defun halfify (list)
  ;; Return two values: a copy of the first half (rounded) of the
  ;; list, and the remainder of it.  
  ;;
  ;; This does essentially two walks down the list (once to compute
  ;; the length, half to build a reversed of the first half and then
  ;; half again to reverse it, and conses as much as the whole list
  ;; (half for the reversed half-copy, half to reverse it).  I don't
  ;; think you can do better than this without code which is
  ;; implicitly destructive, or not tail-recursive.
  (labels ((half (tail n)
             (if (null tail)
                 (split list (round n 2) '())
               (half (rest tail) (1+ n))))
           (split (tail m results)
             (if (zerop m)
                 (values (rev results '()) tail)
               (split (rest tail) (1- m) (cons (first tail) results))))
           (rev (tail result)
             (if (null tail)
                 result
               (rev (rest tail) (cons (first tail) result)))))
    (half list 0)))
```

Finally, I've read Kaz's clever hint, and here's a version which uses that trick. This version will always cut the list before its halfway point if its length is odd.

```
(defun halfify (list)
  (labels ((half/step (fast slow a)
             (if (null fast)
                (values (rev a '()) slow)
               (let ((fast-tail (rest fast)))
                 (if (null fast-tail)
                     (values (rev a '()) slow)
                   (half/step (rest fast-tail) (rest slow)
                              (cons (first slow) a))))))
           (rev (tail result)
             (if (null tail)
                 result
               (rev (rest tail) (cons (first tail) result)))))
    (half/step list list '())))
```